# problem django get() returns two values postgresql

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

hello i have been this problem since i change sqlite to postgresql when it was empty i hit migrate and create tables when i create superuser it bugs but still creates admin users , and when its creates i cannt log in so its basic django admin and should not be something different how can i fix this? is it wrong migrate or?

and this is traceback when i create superuser

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/var/www/html/web/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/var/www/html/web/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/var/www/html/web/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/var/www/html/web/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 79, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/var/www/html/web/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/var/www/html/web/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 189, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
  File "/var/www/html/web/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 157, in create_superuser
    return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
  File "/var/www/html/web/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 140, in _create_user
    user.save(using=self._db)
  File "/var/www/html/web/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 67, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/www/html/web/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 753, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
  File "/var/www/html/web/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 801, in save_base
    post_save.send(
  File "/var/www/html/web/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 177, in send
    return [
  File "/var/www/html/web/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 178, in <listcomp>
    (receiver, receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named))
  File "/var/www/html/web/users/signals.py", line 11, in create_profile
    Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
  File "/var/www/html/web/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/www/html/web/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 447, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/var/www/html/web/users/models.py", line 25, in save
    img = Image.open(self.image.path)
  File "/var/www/html/web/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 57, in path
    return self.storage.path(self.name)
  File "/var/www/html/webst/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 116, in path
    raise NotImplementedError("This backend doesn't support absolute paths.")
NotImplementedError: This backend doesn't support absolute paths.
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have two users with same login. You could try to get all users with login which you use to login in admin panel

```
python manage.py shell
from users.models import User
User.objects.filter(login=your_login)
```

than you will get queryset, and if there more than one object with same login, just delete it

Answer (score 0):

Looks that its something with the settings.py. Please be sure that the settings its ok:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-HOST

Share us the settings.py for more help